# Deadly but important?

Tags: riddle

> I bring death to dry land, yet life would cease without me.
>
> I burn your eyes and your tongue, yet your body needs me.

**What am I?**

(It isn't heat.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are:

> **Salt**

I bring death to dry land, yet life would cease without me.

> [Salting the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_the_earth) makes land unsuitable for growing things, effectively bringing death to dry land.
>  But salt is needed for life.

I burn your eyes and your tongue, yet your body needs me.

> Getting salt in your eyes or tongue makes a burning sensation.
>  But everyone needs salt for fluid balance and muscle and nerve function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Water

I bring death to dry land.

> Obviously rain will mean there is no dry land.

Life would cease without me

> Very true. Life is not possible without water.

I burn your eyes and tongue.

> Salt water burns our eyes and mouth due to different ion  concentration.

Yet the body needs it

> Our body definitely needs water to sustain itself